# python3 getopt.GetoptError: option not recognized

Tags: python, windows, command-line, arguments, getopt

```
optlist, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'l:s:pd', ['load=', 'save=', 'print', 'delete'])
```

I pass the argument `--load duplicates.json` and I get this exception. What's wrong with it?

`raise GetoptError(_('option --%s not recognized') % opt, opt) getopt.GetoptError: option --save duplicates.json not recognized`

I'm on windows in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `=` after your `load` argument.

You should pass the argument like this: `--load=duplicates.json`.